# How do I order items in a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just can't figure this out.

In the `show.html.erb` I want to order items in a join model by a field in that join model.

e.g.

```
Show.html.erb

<% @cycle.cycles_groups.each do |cycle| %>
  <%= cycle.group.name %>
<% end %>
```

I want to order the groups by the group_order field in the cycles_groups table

```
class Cycle

has_many :cycles_groups
has_many :groups, :through => :cycles_groups

class Group

has_many :cycles_groups
has_many :cycles, :through => :cycles_groups

class CyclesGroup

 belongs_to :cycle
 belongs_to :group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a default scope to `CyclesGroup`

```
default_scope -> { order(:group_order) }
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been trying to do this in the controller the same way I would do it in the rails console, and it was driving me nuts!

Comment: And FYI I asked a similar question a while ago that I put a bounty on. If you put the same answer as here, I'll award you the bounty if you want it.

Comment: Cool. I'll give you the bounty as soon as it allows me (18 hours)